# How to make a star plot with igraph?

Tags: r, networking, plot, igraph

I am working with igraph for the first time and would like to do a "star plot"(`make_star()`) with the package `igraph`.

For this I have prepared a sample data set, it has two columns: name and wght.

I want "ME" to be in the center of the plot and all arrows should go out of it. It would be great if the arrow width corresponded to the values ​​from wght (maybe with `edge.width`) OR the weights on the arrows.

**My code looks like this:**

```
library(igraph)
wght <- runif(6, min = 1, max = 10)
name <- c("John", "Jim", "Jack", "Jesse", "Justin", "Peter")
data <- data.frame(name, wght)


st <- make_star(n = 6, mode = "out")
plot(st, vertex.label = data$name)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**what I want:**

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why can't you just replace the name in your data?

Comment: it would work for this example. For the actual problem, it would be better if I could label the central node in the function call. I tried it with: ``` st <- make_star(n=6,mode = "out", central = “ME“)``` but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a graph where "Me" is included as a vertex. Add edge attribute `"weight"`. Create `star` `layout` with "Me" as `center`. Set edge widths according to weights. Plot!

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(data.frame(from = "Me", to = name))
E(g)$weights <- wght

plot(g, layout = layout_as_star(g, center = V(g)["Me"]), edge.width = E(g)$weights)
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
wght <- runif(6, min = 1, max = 10)
name <- c("John", "Jim", "Jack", "Jesse", "Justin", "Peter")
```

Answer (score 1):

Fun to learn about a new package.  This should do it for you:

```
st <- make_star(n=6,mode = "out") %>%
      set_vertex_attr("label", index = 1, value = "ME") %>%
      set_vertex_attr("label", index = 2:6, value = name[2:6])

plot(st)
```

[image]